# Can't edit an active bot version

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, bots

We are deploying Einstein Bot component from an org to other org by using Ant Migration Tool. The same component already exists in the target org and is active. So when we are doing this we are getting the following error in deployment:

**Can't edit an active bot version**

In the target org, we can't deactivate the bot component because it is production org. Is there any way by which we can achieve this without doing any manual work?

Package.xml for the component:


    
        TestBotName
        Bot
    
    45.0

Answer (score 1):

Hope you got the answer by this time, if not here is the workaround.

For the first time, when you deploy your changes to any Sandbox/ Production clone the V1 and let the V1 inactive. Instead activate the cloned copy here it would be V2.

Any consecutive deployments would keep overwriting the V1 and you would no longer face the error "Can't edit an active bot version".

On your git just maintain one version of a bot say V1. For any further changes keep committing your changes to the V1. And after the deployment you could just repeat the same process, clone the V1, here in this instance the cloned copy would be V3,  activate it.